# Cannot open a .xml (working) test plan in JMeter 2.8.20130705 "Conversion Error"

Tags: xml, exception, jmeter, test-plan

I'm facing an error when trying to import a test plan (.xml file) into my JMeter. Here's the error:

```
ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
---- Debugging information ----
message             :org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
cause-exception     :com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy
class               : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
required-type       : org.apache.jorphan.collections.ListedHashTree
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/HTTPSamplerProxy
line number         : 29
```

Line 29 in the .xml:

```
<HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" testname="Petición HTTP" enabled="true">
```

Any ideas why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Java are you using ?
Your version of jmeter is not compatible with Java 8.

Upgrade to jmeter 2.13 and try again.